# Is there an option in karate framework to print the request payload with CURL syntax in the test report

Tags: karate

when there are failures in your test report, sometimes you want to test the api with different parameters to see the behaviour. to do that, it will be easy if the test report contains the request with CURL syntax , so that you can just copy and import to postman and hit it in seconds instead of copying URL, headers, body separately.

Currently I use cucumber reports, and only see the request details logged in plain format

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not an option currently.

Comment: when do you plan his feature to be released?